# Progress widget Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to make a progress bar widget for jupyter notebook with an additional status (in progress).

My widget will have three states - finished, in_progress, not_started. As a result, I expect a shaded part of the widget for the finished share, animated for in_progress and unfilled for not_started.

I will be glad of any information that will help me. Now I have studied the documentation on https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Custom.html but I haven't been able to write my widget yet.

Comment: This would be better suited to the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) after you've done more research. You'll find a lot of resources at the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) that should help you better define the scope of this. For example, beyond Halo, tqdm, and Rich (toggle to open 'progress bars' under 'Rich Library' [here](https://github.com/Textualize/rich#rich-library)) that you can use right alongside your code, JupyterLab already has a lot of components you could build upon [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyter-ui-toolkit).

Comment: https://twitter.com/ptmcguire/status/1498100210576281604